# Почему после редактирования, у меня выскакивает ошибка 404? (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Написал проект про школу, и там есть возможность добавлять, редактировать студента, удалять. Почему то после редактирования студента, он должен сохранится и направить на страницу со списком студентов "allStudent.jsp" Но у меня выскакивает ошибка 404.

editStudent.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <center>
                <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

                <form:form method="POST" action="/editStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                        <input type="hidden" value="${student.id}" name="id"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Name">Имя</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${student.name}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Surname">Фамилия</label></td>
                            <td><input name="surname" value="${student.surname}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Avatar">Фотография:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}"
                                     style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

StudentController.java

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {



    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setName(name);
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }



    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

   @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")

    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id,

            @RequestParam("name") String name,

            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,

            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {
       try {

        studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

     }

    catch (FileSystemException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }

    catch (IOException e) {
         return new ModelAndView("error");
     }

     return "redirect:/allStudents";
}

   @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
         studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }





 }
```

Comment: У вас нет исключения во время выполнения? может быть вы получаете   `ex.printStackTrace();` ?

Comment: Скорее нету, как можно решить проблему

Comment: Так через дебагер пройдитесь по этому методу, посмотрите до куда выходит и что вы получаете в итоге в `mv`. Это самое первое дело при любых ошибках

Comment: У меня он направляет почему то на jsp страницу 404 которую я создал. Хотя в коде думаю все правильно написал

Comment: так по коду в какой момент он перенаправляет? Он заходит в ваш метод `/editStudent`? Если да,то на какой строке он перенаправляет? Попробуйте всю вашу строку с созданием mv заменить на `return "redirect:/allStudents";` в самом конце метода. Если вы говорите, что на вашу собественную 404, то, видимо, у вас происходит переход `return new ModelAndView("error");`

Comment: можете в виде ответа написать как его заменить, я походу что-то неправильно изменяю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94137/discussion-between-dred-and-damagedd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так
Исправьте в editStudent.jsp

```
 <form:form method="POST" action="/SchoolMaven/editStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

и в StudentController сделайте так

```
@PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
public String saveEditedUser(
        @RequestParam("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
        @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

   try {

        studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

     }

    catch (FileSystemException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }

    catch (IOException e) {
         return "redirect:/error";
     }

     return "redirect:/allStudents";
}
```